# Importing Data From Postgres Table into SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql, odbc

Is there a way to read data from PostgreSQL into a SQL Server View ?

I need to access some data in PostgreSQL from my ASP.NET app so I try to read from SQL Server view that already get data from PostgreSQL table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need a way to create a "linked table" over ODBC, using the psqlODBC driver to connect to PostgreSQL. Research SQL server linked tables - pretty sure that's what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, Is there a link explain the idea ?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=SQL+SErver+linked+table+postgresql ? (I've barely used SQL server, so all I'd be doing is searching and finding a good looking result.)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Why can't you just access Postgres directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple.
Step one, download an odbc driver here, according to your system:

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

I found problems installing 09_03_0100 on a clean machine. I suggest 09_02_0100-x64.

Step 2, create an ODBC in System DNS, and test it:
[image: ODBC Configuration]

Step 3, create a linked server:
[image: Linked server configuration]

Step 4, query your linked server like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(PGEXAMPLE, 'select * from yourtable');
```